# Convert boost::ptr_vector<char>::iterator itr to the data in it?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a data in ptr_vector which is char pointer,how to convert it back when looping through items?

```
boost::ptr_vector<char> charlist;
    boost::ptr_vector<char>::iterator itr;

char* result = new char[512];

for ( itr = charlist.begin(); itr != charlist.end(); ++itr )
    {
         strcpy(result,itr);  //doesn't work,
    }
```

the reason I use char* type is that I use boost in an old project.

Comment: Do you seriously have `boost::ptr_vector<char>`? If so, then you may have other problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterators behave as pointers, so to get what they "point" you need to dereference them:

```
strcpy(result, *itr);
```